# How to preprocess features before training a TensorFlow model end-to-end in TF graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

By this piece of code from the documentation, we can create multiple features to feed batches of data into a DNN model:

```
my_feature_columns = []
for key in train_x.keys():
    my_feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key=key))
```

But the problem is what is the proper way to transform the original features before they are fed to the input layer? Typical transformations that I can think of include normalization and clipping.

`tf.feature_column.numeric_column` does have a parameter specifying the normalization function. But the example in the doc only demonstrate a scenario where the normalization factors are pre-defined and fixed, like `lambda x: (x-3.2)/1.5`. How can I perform normalization (e.g. `MinMaxScaler` in sklearn) across all those features without knowing its maximum and minimum beforehand.

Also, is there any pipeline implementation where it's possible to do all sorts of feature transformations before they go into the input layer? Is creating a custom estimator `tf.estimator.Estimator` the answer to this problem? or anything else I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

I can actually answer a part of your question:

> But the example in the doc only demonstrate a scenario where the normalization factors are pre-defined and fixed, like lambda x: (x-3.2)/1.5.

you can simply use **.min** and **.max** class members of a Pandas dataframe to obtain the minimum and maximum of the desired array. Let's say you want to normalize some columns in diabetes dataset, you can do the following:

```
diabetes = pd.read_csv('pima-indians-diabetes.csv', names=new_cols)

# Normalize the columns
cols_to_norm = ['Number_pregnant',
                'Glucose_concentration',
                'Blood_pressure',
                'Triceps',
                'Insulin',
                'BMI',
                'Pedigree']

diabetes[cols_to_norm] = diabetes[cols_to_norm].apply(lambda x: (x - x.min()) / (x.max() - x.min()))
```

Comment: Yeah, but the question is does this approach add the preprocessing step to tensorflow computation graph? Because my model is implemented completely in TF from reading data from disk to get the model results.

Comment: @JamesWong Of course not. This approach is based on Pandas implementation and has nothing to do with TF runtime. For that case, I think you need to implement your own Tensorflow wrappers for array processing. At least it appears to be like that.